# Loading chrome profile with watir uses wrong directory

Tags: ruby, selenium, google-chrome, watir

I´m trying to start chrome with an existing user profile, which profile path I got from checking `chrome://version/`

```
args = ['--user-data-dir=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1']
Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: {args: args}
```

When checking the profile opened via watir per `chrome://version/`, I see that the profile path is `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\Default` with an additional subdirectory `\Default` added ti the path.

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom profile, Its easy in chrome. Assign your own path in `--user-data-dir=` like `user-data-dir=C:\yourname` . Now when you run your program, program opens the chrome, chrome tries to load the profile from the specified directory, If it finds folder is empty, it will create one for you and then it wil load that profile. If you want to customize that chrome, you can do mostly through program.  But if you still want to customize via Browser , then open the browser via program by using debugger and then you open the settings in that browser and do your customization, this will be stored in your directory.

Comment: Thanks for that hint, that´s working and I think it´s an acceptable workaround!